# Create A histogram using C++ with map/unordered_map: the default value for a non-existant key

Tags: c++

I am defining a small function to create a histogram of a vector of integers, Initially I defined the following function that first test whether the key exists in the map before assigning or increment the value.

```
map<int, int> histogram(vector<int> &a){
     map<int, int> hist;
     for (auto &x : a){
         hist[x] = hist.count(x) == 0 ? 1 : hist[x] + 1; // check key existence 
     }
     return hist;
}
```

Later, I found the following code also works without checking the existence of the key. Therefore the default value for a non-existent key is supposed to be ZERO. I am wondering is this behavior guaranteed to have a default zero value when referencing a key that does not exist?

```
map<int, int> histogram(vector<int> &a){
     map<int, int> hist;
     for (auto &x : a){
         hist[x]++;        // without key existence checking. 
     }
     return hist;
}
```

Comment: Not guaranteed, probably true for debug builds.

Comment: @leif Totally guaranteed. The mapped_type elements are *value initialized*.

Comment: If it weren't guaranteed (which it is), then the first method wouldn't fix it: evaluation of the two operands of `=` is unsequenced, so the left-hand side might insert a value before the right-hand side calls `count`.

Comment: @Mike I assume the ternary operator (? : ) evaluates in a short-circuit way. The code does not evaluate the other branch.

Comment: @spacepure: Indeed. But the left-hand side of `=` evaluates `hist[x]`, and so might insert a value before the right-hand side calls `count`. If that value weren't zero, then you'd end up with a bogus value in the map.

Comment: @Mike. right, I think the assignment operator (=) is implemented as both insert and update operations.

Comment: @spacepure: I don't know what you mean by that. It's just a regular assignment, applied to the reference returned by `hist[x]`, to update the value. `[]` does the insertion (if necessary) before returning the reference.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I mean in the case Key x is not present in the map, When hist[x] is referenced, a entry in the map will be created, probably calling the insert method for the map?

Comment: Per [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/)
A call to this function is equivalent to:
(*((this->insert(make_pair(k,mapped_type()))).first)).second

Comment: @spacepure: Yes, as I said in my answer, and a couple of times in these comments, `[]` will insert an entry if it's not there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the value inserted by `[]` is guaranteed to be zero. From C++11 23.4.4.3/1:

> *Effects:* If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.

`T()` specifies value-initialisation which, for numeric types, means it's initialised with the value zero.

Answer (score 5):

It is guaranteed to be zero-initialized for built-in types, and default constructed for user-defined types. The guarantee is that if an element for a given key does not exist, one is inserted, with the mapped_type being *value initialized*. For built-in types such as `int`, this means *zero initialization*.

More information in [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Answer (score 1):

This is a guarantee by the behavior of `std::map`'s [operator `[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) overload. If the key does not exist then it will be value-initialized for you. Since `int`, when value-initialized is assigned to zero, you're safe here.