# vector element compare c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

This program takes a word from text and puts it in a vector; after this it compares every element with the next one.

So I'm trying to compare element of a vector like this:

```
sort(words.begin(), words.end());
int cc = 1;
int compte = 1;
int i;
//browse the vector
for (i = 0; i <= words.size(); i++) {     // comparison
    if (words[i] == words[cc]) { 
        compte = compte + 1; 
    }

    else {     // displaying the word with comparison
        cout << words[i] << " Repeated :  " << compte; printf("\n");
        compte = 1; cc = i;
    }
}
```

My problem in the bounds: `i+1` may exceed the vector borders. How to I handle this case?

Comment: The largest index that can be used to access a vector's elements is `size() - 1`. `i <= words.size()` implies you will access one element beyond that.

Comment: change `i <= words.size()` to `i < words.size()`

Comment: Use `std::size_t`, not `int`, for your loop index. Better yet, use an iterator loop and `std::next()` instead of an index loop. Check against `words.end()` before you use the next iterator.

Comment: Why are you mixing `cout` with `printf`?  Try using `cout << "\n";` to replace the `printf`.

Comment: If you want to build a histogram (count occurrences) see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682716/create-a-histogram-using-c-with-map-unordered-map-the-default-value-for-a-non

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pay more attention on the initial conditions and bounds when you do iteration and comparing at the same time. It is usually a good idea to execute your code using pen and paper at first.

```
sort(words.begin(), words.end()); // make sure !words.empty()
int cc = 0; // index of the word we need to compare.
int compte = 1; // counting of the number of occurrence.
for( size_t i = 1; i < words.size(); ++i ){
    // since you already count the first word, now we are at i=1
    if( words[i] == words[cc] ){
        compte += 1;
    }else{
        // words[i] is going to be different from words[cc].
        cout << words[cc] << " Repeated :  " << compte << '\n';
        compte = 1;
        cc = i;
    }
}
 // to output the last word with its repeat 
cout << words[cc] << " Repeated :  " << compte << '\n';
```

Just for some additional information.
There are better ways to count the number of word appearances.
For example, one can use `unordered_map<string,int>`.

Hope this help.

Comment: why are you casting `words.size()` to `int`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the comments. I have updated.

Comment: @MrrTaQi I'm glad you find it helpful. I encountered the exactly same problem when I was learning programming. You have to make all the mistakes to get better :D This image inspires me all the time: http://i.imgur.com/BFfcsPd.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> My problem in the bounds: i+1 may exceed the vector borders. How to I
>   handle this case?

In modern C++ coding, the problem of an index going past vector bounds can be avoided.  Use the STL containers and avoid using indices.  With a little effort devoted to learning how to use containers this way, you should never see these kind of 'off-by-one' errors again!  As a benefit, the code becomes more easily understood and maintained.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // a test vector of words
    vector< string > words { "alpha", "gamma", "beta", "gamma" };

    // map unique words to their appearance count
    map< string, int > mapwordcount;

    // loop over words
    for( auto& w : words )
    {
        // insert word into map
        auto ret = mapwordcount.insert( pair<string,int>( w, 1 ) );
        if( ! ret.second )
        {
            // word already present
            // so increment count
            ret.first->second++;
        }
    }

    // loop over map
    for( auto& m : mapwordcount )
    {
        cout << "word '" << m.first << "' appears " << m.second << " times\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Produces

```
word 'alpha' appears 1 times
word 'beta' appears 1 times
word 'gamma' appears 2 times
```

https://ideone.com/L9VZt6

If some book or person is teaching you to write code full of

```
for (i = 0; i < ...
```

then you should run away quickly and learn modern coding elsewhere.

Comment: yes but this one cuz me problem with huge file i want to compare while im reading table not to store it in another one and show the other one need just one loop cuz the loop over will take too much time and thanks for ur idiea and sorry for my bad eng :)

Comment: @MrrTaQi "problem with huge file".  How big is your file?  If it is really too big to store in memory ( >> 1Gigabyte ) then you have a whole different problem!  First get your code working properly for reasonably sized files, then look into breaking the file up into sections.  Ask a question something like "How to sort large file that cannot fit in memory"

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses **zero-based indexing**, *e.g.*, an array of length 5 has indices: `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`. This means that index 5 is outside of the range.

Similarly, given an array `arr` of characters:

```
 char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
```

The loop `for (int i = 0; i <= std::size(arr); ++i) { arr[i]; }` will cause a read from outside of the range when `i` is equal to the length of `arr`, which causes undefined behaviour. To avoid this the loop must stop before `i` is equal to the length of the array.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(arr); ++i) { arr[i]; }
```

Also note the use of `std::size_t` as type of the index counter. This is common practice in C++.

---

Now, let's finish with an example of how much easier this can be done using the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

```
std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words));
std::map<std::string, std::size_t> counts;
std::for_each(std::begin(words), std::end(words), [&] (const auto& w) { ++counts[w]; });
```

Output using:

```
for (auto&& [word, count] : counts) {
    std::cout << word << ": " << count << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same repeated words counting using some C++ STL goodies via `multiset` and `upper_bound`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words{ "one", "two", "three", "two", "one" };
    std::multiset<std::string> ms(words.begin(), words.end());
    for (auto it = ms.begin(), end = ms.end(); it != end; it = ms.upper_bound(*it))
        std::cout << *it << " is repeated: " << ms.count(*it) << " times" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/tPYw4a